# Giving exclusive access to certain records in custom object

Tags: sharing, apex-managed-sharing

In this org, I have this custom object, where the OWD is public write/read, and in every profile no one have access to this custom object. access to read and write is granted via permission set.

What folks are looking for is that specific records needs to be write for this user, can be either based on ownership or related lookup to an account record,etc, while everything else read only.

Is there something out of the box or custom code maybe required?

Comment: you can do this without any code using ownership.

Comment: @TusharSharma, using sharing rules?

Comment: @MCHam were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty, No, sharing rules did not work.

Comment: We've done this with a two-step process.  We have a checkbox on User that identifies "Can Edit <object>" and a formula on the record that calculates to TRUE if the write criteria is met.  Lastly we have a validation rule that checks "Can the running user edit?  And is this record editable?"  If both aren't true, the validation rule doesn't allow edits to the page.  Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 0):

To grant access to a record using a manual share:

```
    Click Sharing on the record you want to share.
    Click Add.
    From the Search drop-down list, select the type of group, user, role, or territory to add.
    Choose the specific groups, users, roles, or territories who should have access by adding their names to the Share With list. Use the Add and Remove arrows to move the items from the Available list to the Share With list.
    Choose the access level for the record you are sharing and any associated records that you own.
When sharing a forecast, select Submit Allowed to enable the user, group, or role to submit the forecast.
Select the reason you’re sharing the record so users and administrators can understand.
Click Save.
```

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=granting_access_to_records.htm&language=en)